# Temp table lives after being explicitly dropped

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

I'm creating a post-deployment script in VS2017 database project.
In this script, I'm using single temp table, which is re-created frequently to adjust to different data structures.

Below you can see a sample excerpt:

```
    SELECT
        *
    INTO #tmp
    FROM dbo.SourceTable1
    WHERE
        1 = 0

    drop table #tmp


    SELECT
        *
    INTO #tmp
    FROM dbo.SourceTable2
    WHERE
        1 = 0
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this code, I receive an exception:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 There is already an object named '#tmp' in the database.
```

It looks like the DROP statement is not working here as expected to.
Do you have any idea why does it behave like this?

Comment: Why do you need two temp tables with the same name in the same batch? Why don’t you just call one #tmp1 and the other #tmp2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a batch separator (**GO**) command between the SELECT/DROP/SELECT

[GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.SourceTable1
WHERE 1 = 0

GO

DROP TABLE #tmp

GO

SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.SourceTable2
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: batch separator does the the job. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, according to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) :

_If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names_.